# JQuery selector not working on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have a problem with this jquery selector in Firefox but in Chrome works OK. I'm attaching this event handler after an ajax call. I also tried with `live()` insted of `on()` but the same happened... it worked fine in Chrome but not in Firefox.
The firefox version is 24.0.

Here is my code:

```
$("#paginationlinks > li > a").on("click",function(){
    alert("hello world");});
```

Comment: can you share the html?

Comment: Haven't seen your HTML yet, but this http://jsfiddle.net/H2A9k/ works in Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox requires clicks to have an argument for what is getting clicked on if you want to reference it later (like you would with **.preventDefault**):

```
$("#paginationlinks > li > a").on("click",function(event){
    event.preventDefault;
    alert("hello world");
});
```

Notice the **event** in function(**event**)

Fiddle working in Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/hCE6h/

Fiddle **not** working in Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/hCE6h/1/

Chrome doesn't care either way.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this by using `children()` selector and use of `on()`'s second parameter to specify a selector (rather than using `>` to specify direct descendants):

```
$("#paginationlinks").children("li").on("click", "a", function(){
    alert("hello world");
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/